# Is it possible to parse text documents while loading in Solr?

Tags: solr

I have a text file which contains some data on each line. Each line can be thought of as a database record with fields in that record being separated by semicolon. We will consider each line in the file as a separate document for indexing purposes. For example, consider the following couple lines from the file:

```
1.0.5.32;1.0.5.47;aus;vic;richmond;broadband;-1;-37.8186;144.999;3121;36;28389;43552;3;au;21;0;100;100;100;100;+1100;y;
1.0.5.48;1.0.5.63;aus;vic;melbourne;broadband;-1;-37.8143;144.963;3000;36;28389;5601;3;au;5;0;100;100;100;100;+1100;y;
```

In the example above, we have 2 documents that are to be indexed and each document has 22 fields.

Is it possible to load this text file in Solr and index each line as a separate document, with Solr parsing each document based on delimiter (semicolon in this case) and extracting fields?

If not, is there any way to preprocess the document to convert it into a form that Solr understands?

Answer (score 1):

Look into Solr Wiki, your case clearly described here
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateCSV